# how to build ionic 2 App using phonegap build. Not using CLI

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, ionic2

ionic 2 sample App [link](https://github.com/Gajotres/Ionic2AuthorizationExample) 
Please help to build ionic 2 App using [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_in). I build ionic 1.x app by just moving all things into www folder and override config file. But I cannot find any source in www folder of ionic 2 App.

Comment: Have you asked on the Ionic forum? I also used PGB to build an Ionic 1 app but switched to using the CLI which, as a long time PGB user I highly recommend. I understand why you're having a problem but I don't know how to adapt an Ionic 2 app. Angular 2 is confusing!

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try this set of steps posted for Ionic 2 beta 7

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/building-ionic-2-beta-7-apps-with-phonegap-build/53253

Here's a gulp plugin to support PhoneGap building

- https://github.com/charlesmst/ionic-phonegap-zip

The gap:plugin is [now deprecated](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/plugins/35) for phonegap v6.3.0, so you will need to adapt this gulp script to **not** update `<plugin>` to `<gap:plugin>` .

You also might want to have a look at this gulp plugin that can push your code to phonegap and trigger a rebuild.

- https://github.com/marcbuils/gulp-phonegap-build